# Making a pow(x1, x2) function using only increments, decrements, loops, and =0

Tags: java, pow

Those are the constraints of my problem --- I'm trying to solve this using another computational method, but trying to solve it in Java first. I can read other languages.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static int pow(int x1, int x2){
    if(x1 == 0) return 0;
    if(x2 == 0) return 1;
    int exp = x2;
    int y = x1;
    exp--;
    int multi = x1;

    while(exp != 0) {
        int temp = y;
        while(multi !=0) {
            while (temp != 0) {
                y++;
                temp--;
            }
            multi--;
        }
        exp --;
        multi = x1;
        System.out.println();
    }

    return y;
}
```

`pow(4,4)` should be `256`, but I'm getting `32`. `pow(5,4)` should be `625`, but I'm getting `40`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to get the correct result changing your implementation as little as possible (since it was almost correct!).

Essentially you needed to reuse in the inner while loop the y value you had assigned to temp. I added the variable loopTempY for this purpose.

Another minor change was to the external loop, you only need to loop to greater than 1.

```
public static int pow(int x1, int x2) {
    if (x1 == 0) return 0;
    if (x2 == 0) return 1;
    int exp = x2;
    int y = x1;
    int multi;

    while (exp > 1) {
        multi = x1;
        int temp = y;
        int loopTempY = temp;
        while (multi != 1) {
            while (temp != 0) {
                y++;
                temp--;
            }
            temp = loopTempY;
            multi--;
        }
        exp--;

        System.out.println(y);
    }

    return y;
}
```